# Maven Plugin Signature Check Error

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, jena, apache-jena, animal-sniffer

I am using the following library as dependency:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jena</groupId>
            <artifactId>apache-jena-libs</artifactId>
            <type>pom</type>
            <version>3.2.0</version> <!-- Set version -->
        </dependency>
```

when doing a `mvn clean install`, it is failing and generating the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:animal-sniffer-maven-plugin:1.11:check (signature-check) on project frontend-core: Execution signature-check of goal org.codehaus.mojo:animal-sniffer-maven-plugin:1.11:check failed. IllegalArgumentException -> [Help 1]
```

Any idea about why this error and how to solve it ?
Thanks

Here goes the whole output of `mvn clean install` with the error:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] ESWC 2015 Tutorial
[INFO] ESWC 2015 Tutorial :: Frontend
[INFO] ESWC 2015 Tutorial :: Frontend :: Core
[INFO] ESWC 2015 Tutorial :: Frontend :: Distributable
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building ESWC 2015 Tutorial 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ eswc-2015 ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.3.1:enforce (enforce-maven-3) @ eswc-2015 ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.5.1:unpack (unpack) @ eswc-2015 ---
[INFO] Configured Artifact: org.ldp4j:ldp4j-config:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:jar
[INFO] Unpacking /home/bakerally/.m2/repository/org/ldp4j/ldp4j-config/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/ldp4j-config-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to /home/bakerally/Documents/repositories/github/LDPTest3/target/config with includes "" and excludes ""
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jgit-buildnumber-plugin:1.2.8:extract-buildnumber (git-buildnumber) @ eswc-2015 ---
[INFO] Git info extracted, revision: '2699b4d', branch: 'OSM_Sample', tag: '', commitsCount: '68', buildnumber: '2699b4d'
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- gmaven-plugin:1.0:execute (buildNumber) @ eswc-2015 ---
Build number: 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT build 68 (OSM_Sample@2699b4d)
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.1.201405082137:prepare-agent (default-prepare-agent) @ eswc-2015 ---
[INFO] jacoco.agent.ut.arg set to -javaagent:/home/bakerally/.m2/repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.1.201405082137/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.1.201405082137-runtime.jar=destfile=/home/bakerally/Documents/repositories/github/LDPTest3/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec,includes=org.ldp4j.*
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:1.8:timestamp-property (timestamp-property) @ eswc-2015 ---
[WARNING] Using platform locale (en_US actually) to format date/time, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- license-maven-plugin:2.6:format (update-licenses) @ eswc-2015 ---
[INFO] Updating license headers...
[INFO] Updating license header in: /home/bakerally/Documents/repositories/github/LDPTest3/frontend/dist/pom.xml
[INFO] Updating license header in: /home/bakerally/Documents/repositories/github/LDPTest3/frontend/core/pom.xml
[INFO] Updating license header in: /home/bakerally/Documents/repositories/github/LDPTest3/frontend/pom.xml
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:1.8:add-resource (install-legal-files) @ eswc-2015 ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:1.8:add-resource (install-test-legal-files) @ eswc-2015 ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test (default-test) @ eswc-2015 ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> maven-source-plugin:2.2.1:jar (attach-sources) > generate-sources @ eswc-2015 >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.3.1:enforce (enforce-maven-3) @ eswc-2015 ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.5.1:unpack (unpack) @ eswc-2015 ---
[INFO] Configured Artifact: org.ldp4j:ldp4j-config:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:jar
[INFO] ldp4j-config-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar already unpacked.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jgit-buildnumber-plugin:1.2.8:extract-buildnumber (git-buildnumber) @ eswc-2015 ---
[INFO] Git info extracted, revision: '2699b4d', branch: 'OSM_Sample', tag: '', commitsCount: '68', buildnumber: '2699b4d'
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- gmaven-plugin:1.0:execute (buildNumber) @ eswc-2015 ---
Build number: 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT build 68 (OSM_Sample@2699b4d)
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.1.201405082137:prepare-agent (default-prepare-agent) @ eswc-2015 ---
[INFO] jacoco.agent.ut.arg set to -javaagent:/home/bakerally/.m2/repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.1.201405082137/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.1.201405082137-runtime.jar=destfile=/home/bakerally/Documents/repositories/github/LDPTest3/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec,includes=org.ldp4j.*
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< maven-source-plugin:2.2.1:jar (attach-sources) < generate-sources @ eswc-2015 <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-source-plugin:2.2.1:jar (attach-sources) @ eswc-2015 ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:test-jar (attach-tests) @ eswc-2015 ---
[INFO] Skipping packaging of the test-jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- truezip-maven-plugin:1.1:copy (update-sources) @ eswc-2015 ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-javadoc-plugin:2.10.1:jar (attach-javadocs) @ eswc-2015 ---
[INFO] Not executing Javadoc as the project is not a Java classpath-capable package
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- license-maven-plugin:2.6:check (check-licenses) @ eswc-2015 ---
[INFO] Checking licenses...
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- animal-sniffer-maven-plugin:1.11:check (signature-check) @ eswc-2015 ---
[INFO] Checking unresolved references to org.codehaus.mojo.signature:java16-sun:1.10
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ eswc-2015 ---
[INFO] Installing /home/bakerally/Documents/repositories/github/LDPTest3/pom.xml to /home/bakerally/.m2/repository/org/ldp4j/tutorial/eswc-2015/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/eswc-2015-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building ESWC 2015 Tutorial :: Frontend 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ eswc-2015-frontend ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.3.1:enforce (enforce-maven-3) @ eswc-2015-frontend ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.5.1:unpack (unpack) @ eswc-2015-frontend ---
[INFO] Configured Artifact: org.ldp4j:ldp4j-config:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:jar
[INFO] Unpacking /home/bakerally/.m2/repository/org/ldp4j/ldp4j-config/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/ldp4j-config-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to /home/bakerally/Documents/repositories/github/LDPTest3/frontend/target/config with includes "" and excludes ""
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jgit-buildnumber-plugin:1.2.8:extract-buildnumber (git-buildnumber) @ eswc-2015-frontend ---
[INFO] Git info extracted, revision: '2699b4d', branch: 'OSM_Sample', tag: '', commitsCount: '68', buildnumber: '2699b4d'
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- gmaven-plugin:1.0:execute (buildNumber) @ eswc-2015-frontend ---
Build number: 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT build 68 (OSM_Sample@2699b4d)
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.1.201405082137:prepare-agent (default-prepare-agent) @ eswc-2015-frontend ---
[INFO] jacoco.agent.ut.arg set to -javaagent:/home/bakerally/.m2/repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.1.201405082137/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.1.201405082137-runtime.jar=destfile=/home/bakerally/Documents/repositories/github/LDPTest3/frontend/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec,includes=org.ldp4j.*
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:1.8:timestamp-property (timestamp-property) @ eswc-2015-frontend ---
[WARNING] Using platform locale (en_US actually) to format date/time, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- license-maven-plugin:2.6:format (update-licenses) @ eswc-2015-frontend ---
[INFO] Updating license headers...
[INFO] Updating license header in: /home/bakerally/Documents/repositories/github/LDPTest3/frontend/pom.xml
[INFO] Updating license header in: /home/bakerally/Documents/repositories/github/LDPTest3/frontend/core/pom.xml
[INFO] Updating license header in: /home/bakerally/Documents/repositories/github/LDPTest3/frontend/dist/pom.xml
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:1.8:add-resource (install-legal-files) @ eswc-2015-frontend ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:1.8:add-resource (install-test-legal-files) @ eswc-2015-frontend ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test (default-test) @ eswc-2015-frontend ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> maven-source-plugin:2.2.1:jar (attach-sources) > generate-sources @ eswc-2015-frontend >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.3.1:enforce (enforce-maven-3) @ eswc-2015-frontend ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.5.1:unpack (unpack) @ eswc-2015-frontend ---
[INFO] Configured Artifact: org.ldp4j:ldp4j-config:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:jar
[INFO] ldp4j-config-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar already unpacked.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jgit-buildnumber-plugin:1.2.8:extract-buildnumber (git-buildnumber) @ eswc-2015-frontend ---
[INFO] Git info extracted, revision: '2699b4d', branch: 'OSM_Sample', tag: '', commitsCount: '68', buildnumber: '2699b4d'
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- gmaven-plugin:1.0:execute (buildNumber) @ eswc-2015-frontend ---
Build number: 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT build 68 (OSM_Sample@2699b4d)
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.1.201405082137:prepare-agent (default-prepare-agent) @ eswc-2015-frontend ---
[INFO] jacoco.agent.ut.arg set to -javaagent:/home/bakerally/.m2/repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.1.201405082137/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.1.201405082137-runtime.jar=destfile=/home/bakerally/Documents/repositories/github/LDPTest3/frontend/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec,includes=org.ldp4j.*
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< maven-source-plugin:2.2.1:jar (attach-sources) < generate-sources @ eswc-2015-frontend <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-source-plugin:2.2.1:jar (attach-sources) @ eswc-2015-frontend ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:test-jar (attach-tests) @ eswc-2015-frontend ---
[INFO] Skipping packaging of the test-jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- truezip-maven-plugin:1.1:copy (update-sources) @ eswc-2015-frontend ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-javadoc-plugin:2.10.1:jar (attach-javadocs) @ eswc-2015-frontend ---
[INFO] Not executing Javadoc as the project is not a Java classpath-capable package
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- license-maven-plugin:2.6:check (check-licenses) @ eswc-2015-frontend ---
[INFO] Checking licenses...
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- animal-sniffer-maven-plugin:1.11:check (signature-check) @ eswc-2015-frontend ---
[INFO] Checking unresolved references to org.codehaus.mojo.signature:java16-sun:1.10
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ eswc-2015-frontend ---
[INFO] Installing /home/bakerally/Documents/repositories/github/LDPTest3/frontend/pom.xml to /home/bakerally/.m2/repository/org/ldp4j/tutorial/frontend/eswc-2015-frontend/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/eswc-2015-frontend-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building ESWC 2015 Tutorial :: Frontend :: Core 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ frontend-core ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.3.1:enforce (enforce-maven-3) @ frontend-core ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.5.1:unpack (unpack) @ frontend-core ---
[INFO] Configured Artifact: org.ldp4j:ldp4j-config:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:jar
[INFO] Unpacking /home/bakerally/.m2/repository/org/ldp4j/ldp4j-config/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/ldp4j-config-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to /home/bakerally/Documents/repositories/github/LDPTest3/frontend/core/target/config with includes "" and excludes ""
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jgit-buildnumber-plugin:1.2.8:extract-buildnumber (git-buildnumber) @ frontend-core ---
[INFO] Git info extracted, revision: '2699b4d', branch: 'OSM_Sample', tag: '', commitsCount: '68', buildnumber: '2699b4d'
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- gmaven-plugin:1.0:execute (buildNumber) @ frontend-core ---
Build number: 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT build 68 (OSM_Sample@2699b4d)
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.1.201405082137:prepare-agent (default-prepare-agent) @ frontend-core ---
[INFO] jacoco.agent.ut.arg set to -javaagent:/home/bakerally/.m2/repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.1.201405082137/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.1.201405082137-runtime.jar=destfile=/home/bakerally/Documents/repositories/github/LDPTest3/frontend/core/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec,includes=org.ldp4j.*
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:1.8:timestamp-property (timestamp-property) @ frontend-core ---
[WARNING] Using platform locale (en_US actually) to format date/time, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- license-maven-plugin:2.6:format (update-licenses) @ frontend-core ---
[INFO] Updating license headers...
[INFO] Updating license header in: /home/bakerally/Documents/repositories/github/LDPTest3/frontend/core/pom.xml
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:1.8:add-resource (install-legal-files) @ frontend-core ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:1.8:add-resource (install-test-legal-files) @ frontend-core ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ frontend-core ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/bakerally/Documents/repositories/github/LDPTest3/frontend/core/src/main/resources
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ frontend-core ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 11 source files to /home/bakerally/Documents/repositories/github/LDPTest3/frontend/core/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ frontend-core ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/bakerally/Documents/repositories/github/LDPTest3/frontend/core/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ frontend-core ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test (default-test) @ frontend-core ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ frontend-core ---
[INFO] Building jar: /home/bakerally/Documents/repositories/github/LDPTest3/frontend/core/target/frontend-core-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> maven-source-plugin:2.2.1:jar (attach-sources) > generate-sources @ frontend-core >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.3.1:enforce (enforce-maven-3) @ frontend-core ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.5.1:unpack (unpack) @ frontend-core ---
[INFO] Configured Artifact: org.ldp4j:ldp4j-config:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:jar
[INFO] ldp4j-config-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar already unpacked.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jgit-buildnumber-plugin:1.2.8:extract-buildnumber (git-buildnumber) @ frontend-core ---
[INFO] Git info extracted, revision: '2699b4d', branch: 'OSM_Sample', tag: '', commitsCount: '68', buildnumber: '2699b4d'
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- gmaven-plugin:1.0:execute (buildNumber) @ frontend-core ---
Build number: 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT build 68 (OSM_Sample@2699b4d)
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.1.201405082137:prepare-agent (default-prepare-agent) @ frontend-core ---
[INFO] jacoco.agent.ut.arg set to -javaagent:/home/bakerally/.m2/repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.1.201405082137/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.1.201405082137-runtime.jar=destfile=/home/bakerally/Documents/repositories/github/LDPTest3/frontend/core/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec,includes=org.ldp4j.*
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< maven-source-plugin:2.2.1:jar (attach-sources) < generate-sources @ frontend-core <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-source-plugin:2.2.1:jar (attach-sources) @ frontend-core ---
[INFO] Building jar: /home/bakerally/Documents/repositories/github/LDPTest3/frontend/core/target/frontend-core-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:test-jar (attach-tests) @ frontend-core ---
[INFO] Skipping packaging of the test-jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- truezip-maven-plugin:1.1:copy (update-sources) @ frontend-core ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-javadoc-plugin:2.10.1:jar (attach-javadocs) @ frontend-core ---
[INFO] Building jar: /home/bakerally/Documents/repositories/github/LDPTest3/frontend/core/target/frontend-core-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- license-maven-plugin:2.6:check (check-licenses) @ frontend-core ---
[INFO] Checking licenses...
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- animal-sniffer-maven-plugin:1.11:check (signature-check) @ frontend-core ---
[INFO] Checking unresolved references to org.codehaus.mojo.signature:java16-sun:1.10
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] ESWC 2015 Tutorial ................................. SUCCESS [  6.794 s]
[INFO] ESWC 2015 Tutorial :: Frontend ..................... SUCCESS [  1.307 s]
[INFO] ESWC 2015 Tutorial :: Frontend :: Core ............. FAILURE [  4.140 s]
[INFO] ESWC 2015 Tutorial :: Frontend :: Distributable .... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 12.964 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-03-06T14:53:34+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 51M/476M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:animal-sniffer-maven-plugin:1.11:check (signature-check) on project frontend-core: Execution signature-check of goal org.codehaus.mojo:animal-sniffer-maven-plugin:1.11:check failed. IllegalArgumentException -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :frontend-core
```

Comment: Please post the the whole output there are other information from animal-sniffer-maven-plugin...

Comment: whole output posted

Comment: Can you please check a recent version of [animal-sniffer-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/animal-sniffer/animal-sniffer-maven-plugin/) 1.15?

Comment: the thing is that plugin is transitive dependency while is specified in a third party library

Comment: @Noor two doubts, why use the `type` pom? and if you need the dependency in your project why not include in the dependencies of your project? (If you don't need it, does excluding the dependency help)?

Comment: @nullpointer, removing the "type" doesn't solve, i do need it

Comment: If you need it then try using `<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>animal-sniffer-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.15</version>
</dependency>` in your pom. And exclude the same artifact from any other source.

Comment: when you say any other source, do you mean in apache-jena-libs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may disable checksum in maven.

This is a trick but may work.

http://www.codeoriented.com/how-to-disable-maven-checksum-validation/

Another way is download library and add manually to local repository.

Describe, how do it.
http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

Next another way

In downloads libs with apache-jena-3.2 is example:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.apache.jena</groupId>
  <artifactId>jena-examples</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>Apache Jena - Code Examples</name>
  <description>A collection of example code illustrating uses of Apache Jena</description>
  <url>http://jena.apache.org/</url>

<properties>
  <ver.jena>[3.1.0,)</ver.jena>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<organization>
  <name>Apache Software Foundation</name>
  <url>http://apache.org</url>
</organization>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.jena</groupId>
    <artifactId>apache-jena-libs</artifactId>
    <version>${ver.jena}</version>
    <type>pom</type>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.10</version>
      <type>jar</type>
    <scope>compile</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>

<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>apache-repo-snapshots</id>
    <url>http://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
    <releases>
      <enabled>false</enabled>
    </releases>
    <snapshots>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
    </snapshots>
  </repository>

  <repository>
    <id>apache-repo-releases</id>
    <url>http://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/releases/</url>
    <releases>
     <enabled>true</enabled>
    </releases>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

try set

**[3.1.0,)**

and add repositories

You may before delete library from local repository. In dir M2_HOME.

Comment: i run the command mvn install and it works and it does installs it to the local repo, but after this, do i need to modify my pom.xml anything, because if it doesn't, i get the same error

Comment: @Noor You may try the example in apache-jena-3.20.zip

Comment: ok i changed the version, but still same issue, right now the dependency looks like: <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.jena</groupId>
   <artifactId>jena-tdb</artifactId>
   <version>[3.1.0,)</version>
  </dependency>